# Row larger than the maximum allowed size

Tags: google-bigquery

I have successfully imported many gzipped JSON files on several occasions. For the two files BQ import choked. Both files reported the same error:

> File: 0 / Offset:0 / Line:1 / Column:20971521, Row larger than the maximum allowed size

Now I've read about the row limit of 20MB and I understand that the number above is 20MB +1 but what really bugs me is that the meaning is totally off. My GZs have millions of JSONs (each on a new line). I have written a script to measure the longest line (longest JSON) in the failed GZ file and found it to be 103571 bytes. Why is the BQ import choking then?

I have inspected the longest JSON and it looks perfectly normal. How should I interpret the error? How can I fix it?

Why is BQ thinking the import is on line 1, column 20971521 when there are millions of lines in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the answers here gave me an idea so I went on a tried it. It appears as if for some strange reason BQ didn't like  line endings so I wrote a quick script to rewrite the original input file to use  line endings. Automagically the import worked!

This is utterly strange considering I already imported many GBs of data with pure  line endings.

I am happy that it worked but I could never guess why. I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Can you share a bit more detail here? @wpfwannabe how did you "add line endings"? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All your investigations are correct, but you must check your file as new lines are not identified, and BQ seas all the import as a large line.

That's why it reports column 20971521 for the problem.

You should try importing a sample from the file.

Comment: What do you mean "new lines are not identified"? When I write the script to check for individual lines' lengths, I come up with the numbers I posted in the original question. I don't see how BQ could see everything as one big line. Even if so, the big line would be an invalid JSON and/or not match the schema.

Comment: @wpfwannabe can you share a sample of your data? a job id might help too

Comment: Please see my own answer. Line endings were the key to this one. Not sure why though. The job id was: earnest-stock-91916:bqjob_r63500ded_0000014d5d1c1dcb_1